# How can I save additional data in my Laravel Nova fields?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-nova

I am using [Laravel Nova](https://nova.laravel.com/) and really enjoying it so far.

I have a `Place` field that I am successfully collecting the address, city, state etc.

I would also like to save the geolocation data that is returned by the Algolia API.

Specifically, I want to store:

```
"_geoloc":{"lat":xx.xxx,"lng":-xx.xxx}
```

Is this where an observer comes into play? I have tried that but I am only getting the data from the model. Not the data returned by Algolia.

I would like to say "Hey, save address, city & state like normal, but also save _geoloc into my `lat` and `lng` fields."

I suppose this could go for any any `<insert service here>` where there is some sort of auto-completion going on.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Call the api in your observer